# Как запустить всплывающее уведомление с помощью php

Tags: php, javascript

Имеется шаблон bootstrap и в этом шаблоне имеется возможность использовать всплывающие уведомления, а также имеется инструкция к применению, но к сожалению я не понимаю как запустить с помощью языка php данное уведомление, т.е. именно в тот момент когда нужно.

Вот инструкция, которая написана в шаблоне:

```
Command: toastr["success"]("Действие успешно", "Выполнено!")

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

как мне запустить данное уведомление в подобном примере:

```
if(TRUE){
print "Всплывающее уведомление";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(true) : ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> showNotification(); </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Попробуй так

Comment: а откуда мне взять showNotification();? Мне создать эту функцию и в неё поместить этот код - Command: toastr["success"]("Действие успешно", "Выполнено!"), а также toastr.options?

Comment: Ну это я пример привел,а вы уже называйте вашу функцию как хотите.Создаете функцию внутрь помещаете код вашего уведомления,ну и дальше  при определенном условии вызывайте эту функцию.